# Wrap a DIV with a style around an embedded YouTube video

Tags: css, youtube

I've embedded three YouTube videos onto a page, but I've wrapped them with a DIV and a CLASS called "videoplayer", but the DIV and the CLASS seem to be ignored because they don't display in the page.

You can see it here: http://72.4.166.89/en/tutorial.asp

Here's the CSS being used:

```
.videoplayer {
border: 1px solid #1D740C;
height: 384px;
width: 480px;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
```

}

I've looked with most of my tools and I don't see the DIV or the CLASS having been used at all, but they are there.
Has anyone else run into this, or is this not allowed?

Comment: Could you post the css you used to style the div?? That way we can tell what is missing :)

Comment: Wha'ts really interesting is I've pulled out one of the videoplayer divs and your css into jsfiddle, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/guSAC/  (ps I changed the height to 390px, same height as the player :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating the div to surround the player and adding a class to the div, why not just use the built in class of the player `youtube-player` to apply your styling:

```
.youtube-player{
    border: 1px solid #1D740C;
    height: 390px;
    width: 480px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/guSAC/1/

This by-passes the need to have a parent div and also the problem that you have above :)

hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've given up because even though I can get it to work elsewhere, it refuses to work on that page and I don't really have the time to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The div with class "videoplayer" is on your page but will not *do anything* extraordinary if you do not apply any css style information. If you want to *see* the div, add a background color or border etc. eg.

```
div.videoplayer {
background:black;
border:2px solid red;
padding:10px;
}
```

...or something to that effect.

Comment: That div will be invisible (as it should be) without some style help.  The only style applied to the div is some text-size and a few other irrelevant rules that won't give the div itself any appearance.  @mozami's suggestion will fix it for ya.

Comment: Well in the comment the OP left above (now moved to the post), a border has been added... So that's not entirely true as the border isn't showing up either...

Answer (score 0):

You're div is there, you just can't see it in the browser without some help. What tools did you use? Try firebug, it took me literally 3 seconds to find it with the search feature.

> or is this not allowed?

Its most definitely allowed. Having an object tag inside a div is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out you are missing closing tab for (at least) one of your divs

```
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/icAFUlsysqg?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <!-- you see, there is no closing </div> tag, so put it here -->
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WC0E9jHw1B8?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ayJbo1-ReBc?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
```

And also, you should define some CSS for this class :)

Comment: Oh my god...I CAN'T believe I forgot to close the tag. I must have been more distracted than I thought! Thanks for pointing my error out to me.

Comment: In some situations, this can break your CSS formating, and your browser does not display that formating.